# Certificate of download.postgresql.org has expired

Tags: yum, postgresql-9.6

The ceritifcate of download.postgresql.org has expired and since then, I'm unable to download packages

Comment: What is your question? Visiting that domain with my browser works fine for me.

Comment: **postgresql.org uses a LetsEncrypt certificate** with the (default) 'compatibility' chain to a DST root cert that expired Sept. 30 but still works on old Android. This causes programs using OpenSSL below 1.1.0, which your yum might depending on the distro and packages you're running, to reject the cert if the DST root is in the truststore, although it is valid when checked using the ISRG root (which browsers do @eesiraed). See https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2021/09/13/LetsEncryptRootCertExpire/ and compare to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/671851/ (for Debian).

Comment: I'm running ruby on rails server that need postgresql to connect to the database, since last week i'm unable to use YUM to install the postgres package. I've try to download it with wget and use yum localinstall but the command is failing when checking dependencies

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use flag `--no-check-certificate` (if you are using wget):

`wget --no-check-certificate https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm`

2. you can also try this command on centos 7 to install ca-certificates
   `sudo yum install ca-certificates`